# Alfresco Repository Activity

Tags: alfresco

I would like to see the users activities made in the general repository, without using a site (upload docs,...) in the user dashboard, I have only managed to see the acvitities performed inside user sites. is it possible to do something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create your own activities via the activities services.

Use the [postActivity](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-postActivity.html) to post your own custom activity. The problem remains that you need a required parameter **siteId**.

Probably you can just fill in Repository and if that doesn't work, just create a public site called Repository so it does exist for your need.

You'll need to create a Behaviour to trigger these post as well.